# Send Push Notification to specific App versions

Tags: ios, push-notification, app-store, apple-push-notifications

My app version 1.0 was relying on the text of a push notification alert to show it:

```
{
"aps": {
    "alert": "My text here"
}
```

}

Now for my version 1.1 of the app I localised the app so I need to change my push notifications to allow localisation of these messages:

```
{
"aps": {
    "alert": {
        "title-loc-key": "push_notification..title",
        "loc-key": "push_notification.message",
        "action-loc-key": "push_notification.action"
    },
}
```

}

The problem is that the users that don't update their app to the latest will have the key displayed as the message. Any workarounds for this?

Comment: You should filter out the recipients list based on the app version they have installed. When the Device Token is being uploaded to your server, you should also have the application version in the header request

Comment: Filter your new user's via uploading a value at login time , and in sending notifications scenario check that key , send notification to user's with that key ..

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: No.

Unless you already have the app version associated with each push token, you can't filter on the end-user's device. Filtering must be done on the server's end.

Make sure you store the user's app version when you update the pushtoken and then you'll be able to send the appropriate push payload to each user depending on the version they have installed.